# delphi/IOS: How with PASERVER sign dynamic libraries before to deploy them?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

To include a dynamic library in your iOS app, this dynamic library must be signed. When you deploy an app, Delphi automatically signs the app through the `PASERVER`. Is their anyway to order `PASERVER` to also sign the included dynamic libraries? (that are in the subfolder `Frameworks/` of the app). Or is there any other way to automate this task?

Exactly i need to execute this line before to deploy the app :

```
"/usr/bin/codesign" -s "<myProfile>" "/Users/me/PAServer/scratch-dir/ALLiveVideoChatClient.app/Frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC"
```

Comment: Is this the right approach? Shouldn't frameworks be in the SDK folder and signed beforehand?

Comment: @Hans as I see it's like this that xcode do when we import a framewok from cocoapods, it's put the framework in the Frameworks/ subfolder and sign it

Comment: As a separate process, can you run codesign on the library, then copy the resulting (signed) file back to the Delphi project and add it to the deployment?

Comment: @DaveNottage yes this what I did and it's work, but it's already hard to explain to people how to install my components If I also need to ask them to sign the package :( so I add a bug report: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-22899